# assembly and Visual C++ Express 2010 64 Bit

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, x86, x86-64

Is it possible to insert assembly code on Visual C++ Express 2010 *64 Bit*?

If not, is there an intrinsic for adc (add with carry)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x64 C++ compiler doesn't support inline assembly, you need to put your assembly code in a separate file.

There is no built-in intrinsic for adc, but you can easily emulate it.